# Can I replay Outcore after beating it?

Tags: outcore

At the end of Outcore

> Lumi asks if she can be released into the internet. She says that once you release her she won't come back, which sounds like it's permanent.

Is it possible to replay Outcore after that point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can replay Outcore after beating it.

> After sending Lumi to the internet, she will leave a screenshot of your desktop on your desktop. Drag the photo over K-Lev the dog and the game will restart from the beginning.
>
>
>  If you no longer have said screenshot, according to [a developer post on the Steam forums](https://steamcommunity.com/app/1275670/discussions/0/5533260453828563497/#c5533260453828617026) you can instead tell K-Lev to find Lumi. This will open a new folder where you need to find Lumi's file via the Sonar minigame seen in the game's ending. (If you want to skip the radar minigame, she should be in windows/system32).